# Incorrect Row and Column highlighting in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to highlight the particular row and column at the same time on hovering a table. But somehow only the hovering of column is covering the entire data.

Here is my code:

```css
.planStat {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.planStat tr:hover {
    background: #ffaa00;
 }
.planStat tr:hover td{
      position: relative; 
}
.planStat tr:hover td:hover::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ffa;
      left: 0;
      top: -5000px;
      height: 10000px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1; 
}
```

```html
<table class="planStat">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Name</td>
    <td align="right">Wochenstunden</td>
    <td align="right">Arbeitstage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">SOLL</td>
    <td align="right">IST</td>
    <td align="right">Diff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kdgj6j7/

Where am I going wrong? I tried a lot of combinations, none worked.

Corresponding SASS Code

```
.planStat {
 overflow: hidden;
 tr:hover {
     background: #ffaa00;
     td, th {
         position: relative;
     }
 }
td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffaa00;
    left: 0;
    top: -5000px;
    height: 10000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}}
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase what you want to achieve, it is a bit hard to read.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5kdgj6j7/4/

Comment: I am trying to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rUhCa/

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you wouldn't use the snippet you already provided, what is it you want to change? You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/5kdgj6j7/8/) what i changed, please tell me, is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. But I am trying to achieve it via SASS. I just put the generated CSS code here. I did put z-index as -1 but no color comes on hovering unlike in jsfiddle. Any idea about that?

Comment: Provide the SASS Code and i'll look into it.

Comment: Seems to change the somehow change the priority of `before` and `after` indexing when written in SASS.. absolutely no clue why that is happening tho. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/5kdgj6j7/9/) out, is that what you need, and more important does it work in your enviorment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `z-index` to `-1`

```css
.planStat {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.planStat tr:hover {
    background: #ffaa00;
 }
.planStat tr:hover td{
      position: relative; 
}
.planStat td:hover::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ffa;
      left: 0;
      top: -5000px;
      height: 10000px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1; 
}
```

```html
<table class="planStat">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Name</td>
    <td align="right">Wochenstunden</td>
    <td align="right">Arbeitstage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">SOLL</td>
    <td align="right">IST</td>
    <td align="right">Diff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">SOLL</td>
    <td align="right">IST</td>
    <td align="right">Diff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">SOLL</td>
    <td align="right">IST</td>
    <td align="right">Diff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">SOLL</td>
    <td align="right">IST</td>
    <td align="right">Diff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a no brainer using jQuery. Maybe not a css only solution, but much less code, and easier to read:

```js
$('td').hover(function(){
 var td = $(this);
  td.addClass('highlight') // the hovered td
   .siblings().addClass('highlight'); // the row
  td.parent().siblings()  // other tr's
              .children()  // their td's
              .eq(td.index()) // with the same index as the original td
              .addClass('highlight'); // TADAAAA :-)
}, function(){
 var td = $(this);
  td.removeClass('highlight')
   .siblings().removeClass('highlight');
  td.parent().siblings().children().eq(td.index()).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.planStat td.highlight {
    background: #ffaa00;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="planStat">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Name</td>
    <td align="right">Wochenstunden</td>
    <td align="right">Arbeitstage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">SOLL</td>
    <td align="right">IST</td>
    <td align="right">Diff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Tarekis No he didn't. He just said he tried to achieve this using css. Maybe he is unaware of the js option...? no real reason for the down vote but as you wish..

Comment: Beside the reason using JS for CSS-solvable problems is bad practice, as it needs more performance at the client side, OP tagged it under `css` and stated in the title it is the technology he wants to use and is using. I am downvoting because i think your solution is for the reasons just given not a good one for this problem, and that is the exact reason downvoting is for.